# Data from session NodeJS - Express-session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm having problem with `express-session`, it seems like it's not saving my user session. Here is when I declare my session:

```
// Session
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
    secret: "key per i cookie",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ 
        mongoUrl: process.env.URI,
        autoRemove: 'disabled'
    }),
    cookie: { maxAge:30000, secure:false }
}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.session.user;
    next();
});
```

And then saving it when user is logged in

```
app.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    const user = await User.findOne({username}).lean()

    if(!user) {
        return res.json({status:'error', error:'Username o password non validi'})
    }

    if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            id: user._id, 
            username: user.username
        }, JWT_SECRET);

        req.session.user = username;
        req.session.save();
        console.log('Utente loggato ' + req.session.user);

        return res.json({ status: 'ok', data: token });
    }
    res.json({status:'error',error:'Username o password non validi'});
});
```

Apparently in the post I save the session but after login, when trying to access in an EJS page with

```
<% if(session.user) { %>
    <h1>Session stored</h1>
<% } else { %>
    <p>No session</p>
<% }%>
```

I got no session stored. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the secret phrase used in your session in your cookie parser

```
app.use(cookieParser("key per i cookie"))
```